# Booting Solaris 10 or 11 for Sparc in qemu-system-sparc64

Tags: solaris, qemu, sparc

I'm trying to boot Solaris 10 or Solaris 11 for SPARC using `qemu-system-sparc64` but keep running into problems early on. I'm using the DVD images `sol-10-u11-ga-sparc-dvd.iso` and `sol-11_2-text-sparc.iso` available from SUN's^WOracle's web site.

**Attempting Solaris 10:**

```
$ qemu-system-sparc64 -m 1024 -cdrom /tank/images/sol-10-u11-ga-sparc-dvd.iso -boot d -nographic
OpenBIOS for Sparc64
Configuration device id QEMU version 1 machine id 0
kernel cmdline
CPUs: 1 x SUNW,UltraSPARC-IIi
UUID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Welcome to OpenBIOS v1.1 built on Mar 12 2015 08:09
  Type 'help' for detailed information
Trying cdrom:f...
Not a bootable ELF image
Not a bootable a.out image

Loading FCode image...
Loaded 7420 bytes
entry point is 0x4000
Ignoring failed claim for va 1000000 memsz af6d6!
Ignoring failed claim for va 1402000 memsz 4dcc8!
Ignoring failed claim for va 1800000 memsz 510c8!

Jumping to entry point 00000000010071d8 for type 0000000000000001...
switching to new context: entry point 0x10071d8 stack 0x00000000ffe8aa09
warning:interpret: exception -13 caught
Copyright (c) 1983, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
spacex@:interpret: exception -13 caught
interpret h# d constant MMU_PAGESHIFT h# 0 constant TTE8K h# 20 constant SFHME_SIZE h# 0 constant SFHME_TTE h# 8 constant HMEBLK_TAG h# 0 constant HMEBLK_NEXT h# 2c constant HMEBLK_MISC h# 38 constant HMEBLK_HME1 h# 8 constant NHMENTS h# 7 constant HBLK_SZMASK h# 10 constant HBLK_RANGE_SHIFT h# 8 constant HMEBP_HBLK h# 1 constant HMEBLK_ENDPA h# 20 constant HMEBUCKET_SIZE h# 0 constant HTAG_SFMMUPSZ h# d constant HTAG_BSPAGE_SHIFT h# a constant HTAG_REHASH_SHIFT h# 3ff constant SFMMU_INVALID_SHMERID h# 3 ccould not find debugger-vocabulary-hook>threads:interpret: exception -13 caught
interpret \ Copyright (c) 1995-1999 by Sun Microsystems, Inc.
\ All rights reserved.
\
\ ident "@(#)data64.fth 1.3     00/07/17 SMI"

hex

only forth also definitions
vocabulary kdbg-words
also kdbg-words definitions

defer p@
defer p!
['] x@ is p@
['] x! is p!

8 constant ptrsize

d# 32 constant nbitsminor
h# ffffffff constant maxmin
\
\ Copyright 2008 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
\ Use is subject to license terms.
\

\ #pragma ident "@(#)kdbg.fth   1.20    08/06/06 SMI"

h# 7ff constant v9bias
h# Unhandled Exception 0x0000000000000008
PC = 0x0000000000000000 NPC = 0x0000000000000000
Stopping execution
qemu: fatal: Trap 0x0032 while trap level (5) >= MAXTL (5), Error state
pc: 00000000ffd04640  npc: 00000000ffd04644
%g0-3: 0000000000000000 00000000c40aaab5 00000000c3fb6875 00000000ffe11e38
%g4-7: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
%o0-3: 000001fe020003f8 000001fff0080886 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
%o4-7: 00000000ffeabc00 0000000000000000 00000000ffe812c1 000001fff000ccb8
%l0-3: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
%l4-7: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
%i0-3: 0000000000000000 0000030000f8de5d 0000000000000000 0000000000000002
%i4-7: 0000000000000012 00000000ffe8b000 00000000ffe81371 00000000ffd0c6c0
%f00:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
%f08:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
%f16:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
%f24:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
%f32:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
%f40:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
%f48:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
%f56:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
pstate: 00000015 ccr: 44 (icc: -Z-- xcc: -Z--) asi: 80 tl: 5 pil: 0
cansave: 7 canrestore: 0 otherwin: 0 wstate: 0 cleanwin: 7 cwp: 1
fsr: 0000000000000000 y: 0000000000000000 fprs: 0000000000000000

Abort trap
```

**Attempting Solaris 11:**

```
qemu-system-sparc64 -m 1024 -cdrom /tank/images/sol-11_2-text-sparc.iso -boot d -nographic
OpenBIOS for Sparc64
Configuration device id QEMU version 1 machine id 0
kernel cmdline
CPUs: 1 x SUNW,UltraSPARC-IIi
UUID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Welcome to OpenBIOS v1.1 built on Mar 12 2015 08:09
  Type 'help' for detailed information
Trying cdrom:f...
Not a bootable ELF image
Not a bootable a.out image

Loading FCode image...
Loaded 6636 bytes
entry point is 0x4000
Ignoring failed claim for va 1000000 memsz c107e!
Ignoring failed claim for va 1402000 memsz 5a6e0!
Ignoring failed claim for va 1800000 memsz 52240!

Jumping to entry point 00000000010071f8 for type 0000000000000001...
switching to new context: entry point 0x10071f8 stack 0x00000000ffe8aa09
'SUNW,UltraSPARC-IIi' is not supported by this release of Solaris.
EXIT
0 >
```

I have tried using the `-cpu help` option to find a supported CPU, but no matter what string I provide, it is not understood.

Has anyone gotten original Solaris 10 or 11 to boot with sparc64 under QEMU?
What else should I try?

PS: It is not an option to buy SPARC hardware or emulate 32bit SPARC and ancient Solaris 9 or older or use Solaris x86.

Comment: Have you tried older updates of Solaris 10? Oracle discontinued support of "old processors" (like `SUNW,UltraSPARC-IIi`) in their Solaris releases, so it can be not properly tested in update 11.

Comment: Solaris 10 needs of 2,5 GB of Memory for the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have been searching for this myself a while ago but unfortunately I did not succeed in starting Solaris 10 (or 11) using QEMU with sparc64. I stopped trying after I read the page http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html#QEMU-System-emulator-for-non-PC-targets section 4.3 which states that the emulator is not usable but may boot some kernels.

Answer (score 2):

Qemu-system-sparc64 will boot and run successfully only old versions of Solaris 6 or below with custom bios (taken from old Sparc workstations).
Of course you can try maybe with next releases versions like Solaris 8 or 9
Remind that the kvm module is only for x86 architecture,so Sparc emulation will be really slow.
[This](http://tyom.blogspot.it/2009/12/solaris-under-qemu-how-to.html) is a good how-to to see.

Comment: And i forgot another thing: the qemu-sparc doesn't use the idle feature so it will run with 100% of cpu even the system is idle